# MFC Multiple top-level document application lifecycle

Tags: mfc

I am experimenting with a new MFC multiple top-lever documents application.
I used the VS2019 wizard and created the sample application and now i try to understand the lifecycle of the application.

My main goal is to keep the application open when the last document is closed.

The default behaviour is that after startup, the user can select "New Frame" and create a new frame with its own document and view.
Then, by pressing Close the document closes (with its coresponding frame and view).
But if the user closes the initial document, then the whole application is terminated.

Ideally, i would like to have the ability to keep the application running even when the last document is closed.

Is there a way to have a MainFrame active without a view corellated to it?

Comment: You can modify the wizard-generated code so that there are no "initial" and "additional" top-level windows (ie all having a "Close", rather than an "Exit" menu item), and not closing the whole application when the initial window is closed. The application would close when the last document is closed. Not exactly what you want, but a frame window without a document is of little usefulness, as the only possible operations are close the application or create a new document, which can be achieved by running the application again. It might be possible though, with some code modifications.

Comment: Constantine Georgiou are you referring to some options availeble in the MFC App wizard? Could you elaborate more on this because i couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: I mean the (source) code generated by the Wizard. This can be modified, so as to change its behaviour as desired, like the suggestions I made in my comment above - you need to check the MFC sources too. The Find in Files search of VS is really powerful and can search into the project files, the MFC or CRT sources or their header files. Oh, almost forgot it, Νικ. Παπαδάκης?

Comment: The question I would like to ask is why did you choose the multiple top-level document windows option. The basic difference compared to SDI is that they are under the same process; it's useful only if a document needs to access another one, or if they all need access to a shared resource, for example a connection to a data server or structure which is slow to establish or create, or otherwise "expensive" in terms of resources usage. Otherwise I can't see any advantages over simple SDI. And why do you need an empty frame?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little complicated. In my opinion, the concept of the multi top-level windows application is not the best way it was architectures.

Multi top-level application is in fact SDI application, not MDI, even though the application is using a multi-document template to maintain multiple documents.

As the result of handling the application start in the InitInstance function, the first top frame is treated as the main window and the pointer to this frame is saved as the main window (m_pMainWnd).

Subsequent frames are created as the result of the ID_FILE_NEW_FRAME command, the similar way the first frame is created.

Now, when you close frames, the application compares the pointer of the frame being closed to the pointer of the saved main window. If they are different, the frame is closed and the application is still alive.

To support my initial statement:

notice the behavior of the app (after the creation of several frames), when the frame that was initially created as the main windows is closing. All other frames are also closed.

I think this is an answer to your question: The application is alive until the first created frame window is closed. Regardless of the number of others.

In my opinion, it should close when the closing frame is the only one left. To achieve this, WM_CLOSE (or WM_SYSCOMMAND) command handling would have to be changed.
To fulfill your requirement to keep the last frame alive you would have to use a different approach changing the way all frames are created, possibly using MDI windows to handle your requirement, or simply closing the last document and creating the new one to keep the app running. This approach could be confusing.